# Login failed in ASP MVC 5 and stored procedures

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

I am developing an ASP MVC Application using ADO.net via Stored Procedures.

My problem is that the user cannot login on although the cordinate (Email and Password) are correct.

I developped that using a bool result which get 0 if the cordinate are wrong and 1 if they are correct. But it is take always 0 value !

**Controller :**

```
private void connection()
        {
            string constring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DeliveryCon"].ToString();
            con = new SqlConnection(constring);

        }
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(FormCollection fc, string LastName, string Email)
    {

        int res = dblayer.Admin_Login(fc["Email"], fc["Password"]);
        if (res == 1)
        {
            Session["currentUser"] = Email;
            string z = Email;
            connection();
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select Email from Client", con);

            List<string> result = new List<string>();
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                    result.Add(reader.GetString(0));
                con.Close();
            }
            foreach (string x in result)
            {
                if (x == z)
                {

                    SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand($"select LastName from Client WHERE Email= '{x}' ", con);
                    SqlCommand command3 = new SqlCommand("select count (ClientId) from Client", con);
                    con.Open();
                    string y = command2.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
                    string c = command3.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
                    con.Close();
                    Session["currentUser"] = y;
                    Session["currentEmail"] = Email;

                }
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Profil", "Client");
            Session.RemoveAll();


        }
        else {

            TempData["msg"] = " Email or Password is wrong !";
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

        }

    }
```

Method **Admin_Login :**

```
  public int Admin_Login(string Email, string Password)
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DeliveryCon"].ConnectionString))
            {
                int res = 0;
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SP_Login", con);
                com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", Email);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Password);
                SqlParameter oblogin = new SqlParameter();
                oblogin.ParameterName = "@Isvalid";
                oblogin.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Bit;
                oblogin.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                com.Parameters.Add(oblogin);
                con.Open();
                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                res = Convert.ToInt32(oblogin.Value);
                return res;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            string msg = e.Message;
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

**Db Schema :**

**Table Client :**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Client] (
[ClientId]  INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[FirstName] NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
[LastName]  NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
[Email]     NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
[Phone]     NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
[Address]   NVARCHAR (50)  NULL,
[Password]  NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ClientId] ASC),
UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([Email] ASC)
);
```

**Procedure SP_Login :**

```
create proc SP_Login
@Email nvarchar(50),
@Password nvarchar(max),
@Isvalid bit out
as
begin
Set @Isvalid = (Select COUNT(Email) from Client where Email=@Email and [Password]=@Password)
end
```

and finally **the View :**

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Home", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
                    {

       @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
       @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
       <input value="E-MAIL" name="Email" type="email" required="" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'E-Mail';}" />
       <input value="PASSWORD" name="Password" type="password" required="" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'password';}" />
       <input type="submit" value="login" name="login">
       }
```

Comment: You really should not be storing passwords in plain text. They should be salted and hashed. You might also look at your table definition, the scale of your columns are going to cause you issues. 50 is too short for an email and I don't know of any phone numbers that need 50 characters, and none of them require nvarchar. Address should be more than 1 column. You might also take a peek at this. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Comment: @SeanLange Thanks for the answer but what I am doing now is not an official project which must respect all the common constraints, I am trying only to learn asp mvc through it ! do you have an idea why the res take always 0 as value ?

Comment: Have you tried debugging the code at run time? You can learn a lot about what is going on by evaluating the values being passed at run time. Put in some breakpoints and look at what your code is doing. I don't see the issue but I bet you will find it pretty quickly when you debug this.

Comment: @SeanLange yes I did a breakpoint in each method. For example, In the ActionResult Login, the debugger jump directly to else ! and this is the problem, I am doubt there is an issue with the DB Schema, coz the code was working perfectly but when I updating my db and I don't know what I've changed , this problem appears

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the Admin_Login method. My guess is there an exception being thrown in there and it is returning 0 because that is the value being set initially. Add a try/catch to help you isolate the problem.

Comment: @SeanLange I tried that now but it didn't catch any Exception, I will update my code to see if I use correctly try/catch. Please take a look

Comment: Looks reasonable. You should be able to capture the values being sent to your procedure. You could also setup an extended events session to view the procedure execution. You could setup some logging inside your procedure to record the values being sent in.

Comment: @SeanLange the value sent to my procedures are correct but the problem either like you said the res still as it has been intialized or the Count in stored procedure didn't work

Comment: Have you tried running just the procedure by itself? I really can't do much here because the problem is a bug in your code and I can't debug it from here.

Comment: I know and I appreciate that, I did and I got this Message : There is already an object named 'SP_Login' in the database.

Comment: I think you are confused about how to run a procedure. EXEC SP_Login 'Email, 'Password' But of course you would need to use your values.

Comment: Oh sorry, I did what you suggest and I got this Procedure or function 'SP_Login' expects parameter '@Isvalid', which was not supplied.

Comment: Oops. you need to include that one also. You also need to specify OUTPUT

Comment: ah ok I understand it now and I will try it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160109/discussion-between-exact-and-sean-lange).

Comment: Try to run the code with `int res = 1;` and see if it'll change. Also, this conversion is suspicious `res = Convert.ToInt32(oblogin.Value);`